# debugging TabHost.addTab(TabSpec)

Tags: android, debugging

I am using Eclipse w/ ADT. I am creating the HelloTabWidget app from http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html
When I go to run the app in the emulator it throws an error somewhere in TabHost.addTab(TabSpec), but I am not able to discover what is wrong. I tried to step thru, but there is so much going on inside that call that it takes a long time and I have yet to find out what is wrong.

Does anyone have any recommendations on a better way to debug and find the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured out is that I can put a try/catch around the call to TabHost.addTab(TabSpec). When I do the catch I call an AlertBox as described http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-add-messagebox-in-android.html